# How to search multiline txt files between two known lines in perl

Tags: windows, perl

I am new to perl and am trying to write a program in perl tk. I have most of it but cant seem to get the last bit down.

I am reading in a .txt file that looks something like this...

```
display ("Blue")
....
....
....
....
display ("Yellow")
....
bobby
....
....
display ("Red")
....
.... and so on
```

The "...."s are the sections of data that I dont really care about but I have to search through to find "bobby".

I have built an array that stores all the lines with display in it. i.e. @array. I want to search for "bobby" between each line that has "display" in it within the original .txt file and output whatever display line was above it.

For the example above, I want an output of

display ("Yellow")

I figure I need a while loop to iterate between all of the areas between display I want to seach.

My code below shows some of what I have constructed.
When a button is pressed after the entry is made, the below sub runs.

```
#Output Substation ID to Pane
sub find_substations 
{
       #Copy the entry
my $substation_to_search = $find_ensub->get();

#Insert the copied entry into the outptutext_box
$output_textbox->insert("end", "Substation ID: $substation_to_search\n\n");

       open(myfile1, "file and file location");
       my @lines = <myfile1>;
       #Open File and Print all lines with display in it.
       my @array= grep(/display /,@lines);
       #Array Size
       my $size = @array;
       my $start = $lines[0];
       my $stop = $lines[1];

    while("$x" < "$size")
    {       
     if("$start".."$stop")
     {  
      next if /$start/||/$stop/;
      if()          
      {
        $output_textbox->insert("end", "$lines[0]");
      }#if stop
      }#If stop

     $x++;
     }
   #close myfile1;
```

}

I have been reading about the start and stop but can't get it to work right. Can anyone help me out? The code for the start stop section is not complete.

Comment: For starters, don't needlessly put quotes around variables.  That may also be biting you when trying to treat them as numbers when you do: `"$x" < "$size"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you've overcomplicated the problem. There's no need to track the boundaries (your `$start` and `$end`), only what the current value of `display` is. For example:

**infile:**

```
display ("Blue")
foo
bar
display ("Yellow")
baz
bobby
qux
display ("Red")
pop
bobby
```

**script.pl:**

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 open(my $fh, '<', "./".$ARGV[0]) or die("Cannot open file");

 my $display;
 while (<$fh>) {
   $display = $_ if /^display/;
   print $display if /^bobby$/;
 }
```

Yields:

```
$ perl ./script.pl ./infile
display ("Yellow")
display ("Red")
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasnt sure if there were commands to do what you did above. Perfect. With some modifying It works perfectly.